# MongoDB design speculation

Tags: mongodb

I am digging the MongoDB related questions/answers but one thing is still not obvious.

Let's consider the following Product collection:

```
{
    "manufacturer": "Man1",
    "model": "Model1"
}
```

Let's say we have 1.000.000 products, and I would like to create 
a dropdown of manufacturers (which would be max 50 options).

In this case every time I have to use the .distinct() function on that huge product collection.

Is this the right way to do it ? 
I am a bit concerned about the performance.
Or should I create a separate collection for manufacturers and keep it synced ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the answers, I still considering them.

And what if I do the following:

Manufacturer:

```
{
   "name": "Man1", 
   "models": [
      {
          "name": "Model1", 
          "products": [Product1, Product2]
      }
   ],
}
```

and Product

```
{
    "manufcturer": "Man1",
    "model": "Model1"
    "manufacturer_id": Manufacturer1,
    "model_id", Model1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First. If you've large number of records, you'd never want to load all the data in just one request to populate the list, dropdown or whatever it is. Rather, implementing something like `load more` options suits more. Just like pagination.

And you can manage to get like 20,40 records per request and do any optimization on those small chunk of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate collection for manufacturers. You just have to keep it in sync, after every addition/update/deletion of product from products collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can think of designing your Product collections like this:

{
    "manufacturer": "Man1",
    "model": "Model1"
    "Product" :[Product1,Product2]
}

And having an index on "manufacturer" will optimize your query to get list of manufacturers